# Linux server password has expired. when change the password, no replay

Tags: linux, change-password

My centos server password has expired, notice change password:

```
Last login: Tue Sep 11 11:33:19 2018 from 172.17.x.x
WARNING: Your password has expired.
You must change your password now and login again!
Changing password for user test.
Changing password for test.
(current) UNIX password:
New password:
Retype new password:
```

But, when i input two time new passwrod, the server is waiting... 
no changed success message replay for me, why?
who can help me?

cry cry cry...

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423942/change-password-on-root-user-and-user-account) or [this](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55495).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using ubuntu try this method**

Just goto the GRUB and then select the **Advanced** in the second option
select the **Recovery Mode** in the second option

There you will get an option Called `Drop Your Root shell`
select that and then

```
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue):
# mount -o remount,rw /
# passwd <username>
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
# reboot
```

**If you are using RPM TYPE OS**

As soon as the boot process starts, press ESC to bring up the GRUB boot prompt. You may need to turn the system off from the control panel and then back on to reach the GRUB boot prompt.
You will see a GRUB boot prompt - press "e" to edit the first boot option. (If you do not see the GRUB prompt, you may need to press any key to bring it up before the machine boots)
Find the kernel line (starts with "linux16"), change `ro` to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh`.
Press CTRL-X or F10 to boot single user mode.
Access the system with the command: `chroot /sysroot`.
Run `passwd` to change the root password.
Reboot the system: reboot -f

More Details [Click here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/boot-into-single-user-mode-reset-root-password)